# Is there a compression API that stores state separately?

Tags: compression

I'd like a compression API that allows me to store its state information separately from it's compressed data.

I recognize that to work well I would probably need an API that requires 2 passes: pass 1 over the data to build up its symbol replacement tables and pass 2 to actually compress the data.

Does such an API exist?

Answer (score 0):

Any usable compression library has a state, so that you can compress arbitrarily long streams. Without a state, you would have to give it all of the data in one call.

In addition, any usable compression library is streaming, which means there is only one pass.

[zlib](http://zlib.net) is one example, where the `deflate()` as well as `inflate()` streams maintain an opaque state from call to call referenced in the `z_stream` structure.

Comment: Could I, for example, use the address of a z_stream and sizeof(z_stream) to serialize and deserialize this state?

Comment: If you mean save the state outside the memory environment of the application, then no. There are pointers and allocated memory in the state, so it would take some care to convert to something that could be saved to a file and reloaded.

Comment: There are ways however to bring the deflate compression to an intermediate point using flush options from which a new deflate state could be readily constructed at some later time to restart from that point.

Comment: Are you aware of any example code showing this process?

Comment: Not exactly, and I don't know what exactly you're after here. But you can just read about the `deflate()` flush options and about `deflateSetDictionary()` in zlib.h. It's pretty straightforward.